# finding which timerange includes given time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have time ranges, for example

normal time  : *03:15 - 17:00*

discounttime : *17:00 - 23:10*

night time : *23:10 - 03:15*

And I have to find to which range current time belongs_to.

Before I had  such code:

```
when (3*60+15)..(17*60+00)
  puts "normal_time"
when (17*60+00)..(23*60+10)
  puts "disc_time"
else
  puts "night_time"
end
```

But this code is not working if I have

normal time  : *07:15 - 19:00*

discounttime : *19:00 - 01:10*

night time : *01:10 - 07:15*

Which code should I use to make both configs working?

Should I use 2 days duration?

**Dirty Solution**

I know that the code is not optimized, but it works. I'll refactor it

```
time = Time.now
a = [:normal_time, :disc_time, :night_time]
b = a + [a[0]]
pp = Priceplan.last # has times sets for :normal_time, :disc_time, :night_time

check = time.hour*60+time.min
a.each_with_index do |e, i|
  starts_at = pp.send(e).hour * 60 + pp.send(e).min
  ends_at  = pp.send(b[i+1]).hour * 60 + pp.send(b[i+1]).min
  if starts_at < ends_at
if (starts_at..ends_at).include?(check)
  p "ok!!!!!!!! at #{e}"
  break
end
  else
if (starts_at..(24*60)).include?(check)
  p "ok!!!!!!!! at #{e} (divided first)"
  break
elsif (0..ends_at).include?(check)
  p "ok!!!!!!!! at #{e} (divided second)"
  break
end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Ranges always run from low numbers to higher numbers. When you have a range like: `19:00-01:10` you're creating an invalid range. To fix it just divide up the ranges so that you have `19:00-23:59` and then a new range `00:00-01:10` to cover the rest of the timespan.

Comment: Thanks for the answer as well, I put my dirty solution into my question

Answer (score 1):

You can try using today midnight as a base point

```
def today_midnight
  Time.now.utc.midnight
end

normal time : where(:belongs_to => (today_midnight + 7.hours + 15.minutes) .. (today_midnight + 19.hours))

discount time : where(:belongs_to => (today_midnight + 1.hours + 10.minutes) .. (today_midnight + 19.hours))

night time: where(:belongs_to => (today_midnight + 1.hour + 10.minutes) .. (today_midnight + 7.hours + 15.minutes))
```

Though long, I believe writing in such a manner makes the code a lot more readable. i.e. a  year after, if you'll be able to understand whats going on by quickly looking at the code.

Comment: Unfortunately,discount time is not working as (today_midnight + 19.hours) is bigger than (today_midnight + 1.hours + 10.minutes)

Comment: Ahh yes. Nice catch. You can flip it. I'm editing in the post

Comment: but now here is more serious problem. Discount_time covers normal_time but it shouldn't be so :(